# How to make windows service from the Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: windows-services, eclipse-rcp

I am new for eclipse RCP application for making Service.
How can I make it service? Please tell me what is the step required to do this?

My System configuration is WIn 10 64 bit. 
 Eclipse Kepler For RAP and RCP Developer.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you properly you want to call you RCP app by command line to do some service.

so you have to select which plugin in your RCP will provide the service and use the extension

> "org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications"

which will force you to create a class which implements IApplication Interface, in which you will call whatever service you need in

> "Object start(IApplicationContext context) " method.

hence you can call and run this plugin as a service from command line by tying in cmd :

> [RCP Path]eclipsec -nosplash -application [Plugin name]

but make sure that eclipsec.exe exists in your RCP